# Pandas Dataframe apply() function

Tags: python, pandas

I am running this Junyper Notebook: https://github.com/jillishii/EtsyAnalysis/blob/master/Data_Aquisition.ipynb

and I am having trouble with this line:

```
# Apply function and story multiple page urls in column called page_nums
catdf['page_nums'] = catdf.apply(get_page2, axis=1)
```

[image]

[image]

I am not sure what the error is caused by. I want to be able to run this notebook.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Please state your problem.

Comment: I would like to run the notebook.

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.  [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... 
[Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there appears to be a problem with the code that's generating `subcategory_links.csv`, it comes up empty. if you use the existing file in the repo, which is not empty, the code-cell that you're referring to runs without error. hope that helps.